# Do we release all consonant sounds that appear at the end of the word which ends the sentence in AmE?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

Do we release all the consonant sounds that appear at the end of the word ending a sentence?

**Examples:**

1. I am at work.
2. There was a Big Bang.
3. I have a new hope.
4. He has a big heart.

Comment: I think *on average* Americans are more likely to "release" final consonants than Brits. As a Brit myself, and often not a particularly "careful" speaker, I tend to just finish such utterances with a glottal stop. So the only reason you'd know I wasn't saying *I'm at **wort*** is because you know the word ***wort*** wouldn't make sense there (there would be no clue from the way I normally articulated it). Equally, I might be saying *He has a big **harp***, and you'd have no way of knowing.

Comment: Being a continuant, /ŋ/ does not actually have a release at all. The other three, being plosives, do have releases but may be unreleased utterance-finally.